# Summing rows on certain conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-analysis

I have a dataframe of the following kind. This is just a small sample of the dataset. It has a high no of rows.

```
df <- data.frame(team = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"),
                 Skill     = c("TSICS", "TSICS", "TSICS", "TSICS", "COHORT", "COHORT"),
                 Date = c("1/1/2020","7/1/2020", "14/1/2020", "21/1/2020", "7/1/2020", "21/2/2020" ),
                 Value = (10,20,30,5,6,23)
)
>df
   Team    Skill       Date         Value
     A     TSICS       1/1/2020      10
     A     TSICS       7/1/2020      20
     A     TSICS       14/1/2020     30
     A     TSICS       21/1/2020      5
     A     COHORT      7/1/2020       6
     B     COHORT      21/2/2020     23
```

I want to create a new column Result which is
Result = Value[team= A, Skill = TSICS] + Value[team= A, Skill = Cohort] corresponding to that team and Date(1 week previous to the corresponding date).

**Please note: The values for a particular date should be picked from the previous date.
For eg: For Team A: Skill = TSICS the value for 21/1/2020 = 30 i.e the previous date value.
This the resultant table should be of the form

```
Team    Skill       Date         Value      Result
     A     TSICS       1/1/2020      10        0 (no previous date values for TSICS(A) & Cohort(A))
     A     TSICS       7/1/2020      20       10 (only previous date value for TSICS(A))
     A     TSICS       14/1/2020     30       26 (sum of previous date values for TSICS(A) & Cohort(A))
     A     TSICS       21/1/2020      5       30 (previous date value of TSICS(A))
     A     COHORT      7/1/2020       6       10 (previous date value of TSICS(A))
     B     COHORT      21/2/2020     23       0  (no previous date value)
```

Can we use lag function to get the previous date value?
*The dates are in dd-mm-yyyy format*

Comment: Why does the Team in line 5 switch from B to A? Presume the example has a typo?

Comment: Can we ignore Skill when computing Result since your example shows Result is dependent only on Date and Team?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It is suppose to be A. Thanks for bringing it to my notice

Comment: Skill, team and Date all are required to compute the results

Comment: Since the days aren't separated by even weeks (1/1 to 7/1 is 6 days, 21/1 to 21/2 is 31 days), what is your definition of "1 week previous"? Is 6 days close enough?

Comment: Yes. 6 days works .

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) 

df %>%
  group_split(team) %>%
  map(., ~.x %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(Result = sum(ifelse(.$Date >= (Date - 8) & .$Date < Date, .$Value, 0)))) %>%
  bind_rows()

 A tibble: 6 x 5
# Rowwise: 
  team  Skill  Date       Value Result
  <fct> <fct>  <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     TSICS  2020-01-01    10      0
2 A     TSICS  2020-01-07    20     10
3 A     TSICS  2020-01-14    30     26
4 A     TSICS  2020-01-21     5     30
5 A     COHORT 2020-01-07     6     10
6 B     COHORT 2020-02-21    23      0
```

Comment: Nice approach! You could use `group_by(team) %>% group_modify(~ .x %>% …)` instead of `group_split %>% map` which would save you the `bind_rows` in the end.